# How to make alpha blending (transparency) at outside of rounded corner on fragment shader?

Tags: glsl, shader, rounded-corners

I wanted rounded corner by using fragment shader and make some codes like below.

```
vec2 size = vec2(320.0, 240.0);
vec2 location = vec2(160.0, 720.0);
float edgeSoftness  = 2.0;
float radius = 40.0;
float d = udRoundBox(gl_FragCoord.xy - location, size / 2.0, radius);
gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(texture2D(tex, coords.xy).rgb, vec3(0.0), smoothstep(0.0, 0.0,d)), 1.0);
```

And the result is
[image]

The rounded corner is applied I wanted but the background color is just black.
There is the other texture on red background so I want that the black background become alpha blending but I don't know how make it.
I know I can get out side of rounded corner by below code but I don't know what to do next.

```
vec4 outside = vec4(mix(texture2D(tex, coords.xy).rgb, vec3(0.0), 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, 0.0,d)), 1.0)
```

Can you help this?
FYI, I already added below codes.

```
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this simply.
Just add '1.0 - smoothstep-result' on alpha value.

```
vec2 size = vec2(320.0, 240.0);
vec2 location = vec2(160.0, 720.0);
float edgeSoftness  = 2.0;
float radius = 40.0;
float d = udRoundBox(gl_FragCoord.xy - location, size / 2.0, radius);
float s = smoothstep(0.0, 0.0,d);
vec4 c = vec4(mix(texture2D(tex, coords.xy).rgb, vec3(0.0), s), 1.0 - s);
gl_FragColor = c;
```